Ktor client throws an IO Exception in Android in http 200 response
When I call an endpoint, I receive an io exception; however, on my mobile device, I receive the push notification (that's expected), and the network inspector says that the response is HTTP 200. I don't except any body in my answer I'm simply care if this is an ok HTTP or something else.
return flow {
  try {
    Timber.e("POINT, 1")

    val response: HttpResponse = httpClient.post(url) {
      setBody(enrolmentRequestData)
    }
    Timber.e("POINT, 1 2, ${response.status.value}")
    Timber.e("POINT, 1 2, Response body: ${response.bodyAsText()}") // Add this to log the response body if possible

    if (response.status == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
      emit(Result.Success(Unit))
    } else {
      handleErrorResponse(response.status.value)
    }
  } catch (e: ResponseException) {
    Timber.e("ResponseException: ${e.response.status.value}, ${e.message}")
    handleErrorResponse(e.response.status.value)
  } catch (e: JSONException) {
    Timber.e("JSONException: ${e.message}")
    emit(Result.Error(DataError.Network.JSON_PARSE_EXCEPTION))
  } catch (e: IOException) {
    Timber.e("IOException: ${e.message}, ${e.stackTrace}}")
    e.printStackTrace() // Print full stack trace for better analysis
    emit(Result.Error(DataError.Network.NO_INTERNET))
  } catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.e("Unknown Exception: ${e.message}, ${e.stackTrace}")
    emit(Result.Error(DataError.Network.UNKNOWN_ERROR))
  }
}
}

I see point 1 in my logs, and after that, only this:
E  IOException: null, [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@15c8851}
2024-06-28 22:15:39.704 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  java.io.EOFException
2024-06-28 22:15:39.704 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.704 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.704 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.utils.io.ExceptionUtilsJvmKt$createConstructor$$inlined$safeCtor$3.invoke(SourceFile:81)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.704 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.utils.io.ExceptionUtilsJvmKt$createConstructor$$inlined$safeCtor$3.invoke(SourceFile:90)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.704 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.utils.io.ExceptionUtilsJvmKt.tryCopyException(SourceFile:66)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.704 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannelKt.rethrowClosed(SourceFile:2404)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.704 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannelKt.access$rethrowClosed(SourceFile:1)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel.readRemaining$suspendImpl(SourceFile:2063)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel.readRemaining(Unknown Source:0)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.utils.io.ByteReadChannel$DefaultImpls.readRemaining$default(SourceFile:88)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.client.call.SavedCallKt.save(SourceFile:73)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement$execute$4.invokeSuspend(SourceFile:63)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement$execute$4.invoke(SourceFile:0)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement$execute$4.invoke(SourceFile:0)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement.execute(SourceFile:50)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.client.statement.HttpStatement$execute$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:12)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(SourceFile:33)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(SourceFile:102)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(SourceFile:65)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuation.resumeWith(SourceFile:199)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(SourceFile:135)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SourceFile:109)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(SourceFile:11)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(SourceFile:59)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(SourceFile:46)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(SourceFile:102)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:959)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:232)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:317)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.705 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8592)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.706 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.706 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
2024-06-28 22:15:39.706 24066-24066 System.err  eu.europa.ec.ecas W  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:878)


2.3.12 is the library I'm using

Could you share the Content-Encoding and Transfer-Encoding of your server response? In my case it's gzip and chunked with empty body, maybe that's what causing the issue? PS: This server is not adding Content-Length header, maybe that's what caused readRemaining() runs into EOF? (without that It'll read to Int.MAX_VALUE)

I received a confirmation from Jetbrains that the issue is this:
By default, the Ktor client saves the entire response body into the memory to allow multiple HttpResponse.body calls. You can use the HttpStatement.execute method to avoid that behavior, where the response body may be discarded. Here is an example:
val responseFlow = flow {
    client.preparePost("https://httpbin.org/post") {
        setBody("test")
    }.execute { response ->
        if (response.status == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            emit(Result.success(Unit))
        } else {
            // handleErrorResponse(response.status.value)
        }

        response.discardRemaining()
    }
}


Generally, with this now, I see the proper response, but it still throws the IO exception. I will keep you posted on the answer from the JetBrains team here.

I've tried your solution and notice the exception is now happening in discardRemaining() line. Not calling it seemed fine but IMHO not feeling quite right. Would you mind sharing the link to the JetBrains inquiry?

If you are not expecting any body in your response then why are you trying to print the body in your log message?
Timber.e("POINT, 1 2, Response body: ${response.bodyAsText()}")

That is why you are getting an EOFException which means the stream unexpectedly reached the end when trying to read it

I don't think that is the problem because the second log is not even printed.

I've deleted that and am still getting the same error.

the maybe its something with the data you send in the body. Regardless the error you are getting is because something is being read with nothing there

But it looks fine because, as I've said, I see 200, and the server responded correctly.
